# How to exempt an element within a tag from the latter's behavior?

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation, event-propagation

On my page I have a large `a` element containing different things including a "open_modal" button that opens some Bootstrap modal window. When clicking anywhere within the `a` element I want normal behavior to occur, but clicking on the "open_modal" should only open the modal window (taken care of through Bootstrap modal classes).

HTML:

```
<a href='example.com'>
    <div class='open_modal'>doing something else</div>
</a>
```

Using `stopPropagation()` with the button successfully removes the `a` behavior from it but unfortunately it also removes the Bootstrap modal functionality attached to it so it doesn't do anything anymore:

```
$( '.open_modal' ).click(function(event) {    
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `preventDefault()` instead of `stopPropagation()`.
`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain ( i.e, the events registered in the chain would not invoke ) while
`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event ( i.e, prevents just the default behavior of the current event ).

```
$( '.open_modal' ).click(function(event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
});
```